# Deleting EXIF metadata from pictures

Tags: java, file-system, console

My app is about deleting exif metadata from pictures. Also, what do you think about the code quality (OOP principles, clean code)? Is it production-ready?

[GitHub](https://github.com/kivimango/metawipe/tree/1ad6641d8bf721ffa5e15bbcfb0fbe0981e52734)

MetaWipe.java

```
public final class MetaWipe {

private final ArgumentResolver resolver = new ArgumentResolver();
private final ExifEraserService eraser = new ExifEraserServiceImpl();
private CommandLine params = null;

private static final char FILE_ARG = 'f';
private static final char DIR_ARG = 'd';
private static final String HELP_ARG = "help";

private static final String VERSION = "0.1";

private void run(final String[] args) {
    parseCommandLineArguments(args);
    if(params != null) {
        if (params.hasOption(FILE_ARG) && (!params.hasOption(DIR_ARG) && !params.hasOption(HELP_ARG))) {
            tryEraseExifOrExitOnFailure(params.getOptionValue(FILE_ARG));
        } else if (params.hasOption(DIR_ARG) && !params.hasOption(FILE_ARG)) {
            tryEraseExifInDir(params.getOptionValue(DIR_ARG));
        } else if(params.hasOption(HELP_ARG) && (!params.hasOption(FILE_ARG) && !params.hasOption(DIR_ARG))) {
            resolver.displayUsage();
        } else {
            displayInfo();
        }
    } else resolver.displayUsage();
}

private void tryEraseExifInDir(final String pathValue) {
    if (!empty(pathValue)) {
        try {
            final Path dir = Paths.get(pathValue);
            eraser.directory(dir);
        } catch (NotDirectoryException nde) {
           exitWithErrorMessage("This is not a directory: " + pathValue, 2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
            exitWithErrorMessage("Directory not found : " + pathValue, 2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exitWithErrorMessage("An I/O error occurred: " + e.getMessage(), 2);
        }
    } else {
        exitWithErrorMessage("You must supply a path", 1);
    }
}

private void tryEraseExifOrExitOnFailure(final String pathValue) {
    if (!empty(pathValue)) {
        try {
            final Path path = Paths.get(pathValue);
            eraser.file(path);
        } catch (NotAFileException nfe) {
            exitWithErrorMessage("This is not a file! " + pathValue, 2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            exitWithErrorMessage("File not found! " + pathValue, 2);
        } catch (ImageReadException ire) {
            exitWithErrorMessage("Can't read image! " + ire.getMessage(), 4);
        } catch (ImageWriteException iwe) {
            exitWithErrorMessage("Can't write image! " + iwe.getMessage(), 4);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            exitWithErrorMessage("An I/O error occurred: " + e.getMessage(), 2);
        }
    } else {
        exitWithErrorMessage("You must supply a path !", 1);
    }
}

private void parseCommandLineArguments(String[] args) {
    try {
        params = resolver.parseCommandLineArguments(args);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        exitWithErrorMessage("Invalid parameters !", 1);
    }
}

private boolean empty(String str) {
    return str == null || str.trim().isEmpty();
}

private void exitWithErrorMessage(String msg, int exitCode) {
    System.out.println(msg);
    resolver.displayUsage();
    System.exit(exitCode);
}

private void displayInfo() {
    System.out.println("metawipe (Version: " + VERSION +")");
    System.out.println("Small command-line tool to clear the metadata/exif records of your photos to give back the control over security and privacy.");
    System.out.println("It is useful to clear metadata before uploading your photos to cloud like Facebook, Google, etc if you don't want to share your GPS location");
    System.out.println("and other sensitive data with anyone.");
    System.out.println("Type <metawipe -help> to display the help.");
    System.out.println("Visit https://github.com/kivimango/metawipe for more info.");
}

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    MetaWipe app = new MetaWipe();
    app.run(args);
}

}
```

ArgumentResolver.java

```
final class ArgumentResolver {

private static final String FILE_FLAG = "f";
private static final String DIR_FLAG = "d";
private static final String HELP_FLAG = "help";

private final Options flagOptions = new Options();
private final CommandLineParser parser = new DefaultParser();

ArgumentResolver() {
    makeOptions();
}

private void makeOptions() {
    Option fileOption = Option.builder(FILE_FLAG).optionalArg(true).argName("file").hasArg().desc("Clears metadata of the given photo").build();
    Option dirOption = Option.builder(DIR_FLAG).optionalArg(true).argName("dir").hasArg().desc("Clears every photo in a directory and its subdirectories recursively").build();
    Option helpOption = Option.builder(HELP_FLAG).optionalArg(true).argName("help").hasArg(false).desc("Displays this help").build();
    flagOptions.addOption(fileOption);
    flagOptions.addOption(dirOption);
    flagOptions.addOption(helpOption);
}

final CommandLine parseCommandLineArguments(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    return parser.parse(flagOptions, args);
}

final void displayUsage() {
    final HelpFormatter formatter = new HelpFormatter();
    formatter.printHelp( "metawipe", flagOptions);
}

}
```

ExifEraserServiceImpl.java

```
public final class ExifEraserServiceImpl implements ExifEraserService {

private final ExifRewriter rewriter = new ExifRewriter();
private final List<String> supportedFormats = Arrays.asList("jpg", "jpeg", "tiff");

@Override
public final void directory(final Path dir) throws IOException {
    if(!Files.exists(dir)) throw new FileNotFoundException();
    if(!Files.isDirectory(dir)) {
        throw new NotDirectoryException(dir.toString());
    } else {
        Files.walkFileTree(dir, new RecursiveDirectoryWalker(this));
    }
}

/**
 * Before deleting exif data of the image, we have to make a copy of it.
 * Otherwise Imaging library will throw an EOF exception if we want to read and write to the same file.
 * After successful deletion, the copy gets renamed to the original file, and the original file will be overridden.
 */

@Override
public final boolean file(final Path file) throws IOException, ImageWriteException, ImageReadException, NotAFileException {
    if(!Files.exists(file)) throw new FileNotFoundException();
    if(Files.isDirectory(file)) throw new NotAFileException();
    if(supportedFormats.contains(FileNameResolver.getExtension(file))) {
        final Path copiedFile = makeCopy(file);
        deleteExifMetaData(file, copiedFile);
        Files.move(copiedFile, file, REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    return checkExifDeleted(file);
}

private void deleteExifMetaData(final Path f, final Path copy) throws IOException, ImageWriteException, ImageReadException {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(copy.toFile()); OutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(fos)) {
        try{
            rewriter.removeExifMetadata(f.toFile(), os);
            /* During deleting, exceptions may occur.
            In this case, we have to delete the copy of the original file */
        } catch (ImageReadException e) {
            Files.deleteIfExists(copy);
            throw new ImageReadException(e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (ImageWriteException e) {
            Files.deleteIfExists(copy);
            throw new ImageWriteException(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}

Path makeCopy(final Path original) throws IOException {
    final String tempFileName = FileNameResolver.getFilePath(original) + File.separator +
            FileNameResolver.getFileNameWithoutExtension(original) + "_copy." + FileNameResolver.getExtension(original);
    final Path copiedFilePath = Paths.get(tempFileName);
    if(Files.exists(copiedFilePath)) { Files.deleteIfExists(copiedFilePath); }
    Files.copy(original, copiedFilePath);
    return copiedFilePath;
}

boolean checkExifDeleted(final Path f) throws IOException, ImageReadException {
    // Sometimes metadata is null even if the exif records deleted
    final IImageMetadata metadata = Imaging.getMetadata(f.toFile());
    return metadata == null || metadata.toString().contains("No Exif metadata.");
}

}
```

RecursiveDirectoryWalker.java

```
class RecursiveDirectoryWalker implements FileVisitor<Path> {

private final PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**.{jpg,jpeg,tiff}");
private ExifEraserService eraser;

RecursiveDirectoryWalker(ExifEraserService eraser) {
    this.eraser = eraser;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult preVisitDirectory(Path dir, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    Stream<Path> list = Files.list(dir);
    if (list != null) {
        list.filter(matcher::matches)
                .forEach((Path f) -> {
                    try {
                        eraser.file(f);
                    } catch (ImageWriteException | ImageReadException | IOException ie) {
                        System.out.println("Error: " + ie);
                    } catch (NotAFileException ignore) {
                    }
                });
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    if(matcher.matches(file)) {
        try {
            eraser.file(file);
        } catch (ImageWriteException | ImageReadException ie) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + ie);
        } catch (NotAFileException ignore) {
        }
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
    if(exc != null) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + exc);
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
    if(exc != null) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + exc);
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}
}
```

FileNameResolver.java

```
final class FileNameResolver {

static String getFilePath(final Path file) {
    String absolutePath = file.toAbsolutePath().toString();
    return absolutePath.substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));
}

// TODO : duplicate code

static String getFileNameWithoutExtension(final Path file) {
    String fileName = file.getFileName().toString();
    int pos = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (pos > 0) {
        fileName = fileName.substring(0, pos);
    }
    return fileName;
}

static String getExtension(final Path file) {
    String fileName = file.getFileName().toString();
    int pos = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (pos > 0) {
        fileName = fileName.substring(pos + 1);
    }
    return fileName;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The formatting is inconsistent, perhaps let the IDE do it if you're
  using one.
- It's a bit verbose, that goes both for the classes present here as
  well as the test code in the repository.  If a variable is only
  defined and used two times I really don't see the point of having it,
  outside perhaps of the minor argument that it helps in not-so-great
  debuggers.
- Same goes for the constants in the `ArgumentResolver` class.  Other
  than that the class looks okay, having a dedicated piece to parse
  command line options is good; again `displayUsage` could just be
  `new HelpFormatter().printHelp("metawipe", flagOptions);` and you'd
  already have eliminated about four tokens to mentally process.
- I'd guess that PNG files can have EXIF metadata?  What about other
  file formats that the used library supports?
- Use better method names - `file`, `directory` are at best variable
  names, but don't say anything about what the method does.  In this
  case (`ExifEraserService`) I'd consider `visitFile`, `processFile`, or
  even `deleteExifFromFile` or so on.
- The general pattern of copying the file, editing it, then moving it
  over the old one is good.  I don't get why `checkExifDeleted` is
  necessary but I guess there are technicalities involved?  The check
  via `toString().contains(...)` sounds like a hack though, would that
  still work if the metadata itself contains that string (as a title or
  comment or whatever)?
- `makeCopy` is dangerous (what if the user has an actual file with the
  "temporary" name?).  Consider using `java.io.Files.createTempFile` or
  even `java.nio.Files.createTempDirectory` instead.
- The `catch`s in `deleteExifMetaData` can be a single case I think, as
  you've already done in `preVisitDirectory`.
- `FileNameResolver` has duplicate code as you've already written ...
- Finally `MetaWipe` has the constants duplicated for some reason?  The
  handlers in `run` look weird, just put them in the order they should
  be handled and exit early - if `-h` is already specified, why do you
  care if some other options is set as well?
- The exception handling is again a bit verbose, I understand that you
  want to provide nice error messages, but there's again a lot of
  duplication here and I'd drop the different exit statuses, do you
  really check those?
- Also for both `try...` methods, maybe invert the check:
  `if (empty(pathValue)) exit...; ...` then you can eliminate one level
  of nesting already.
- Just a general note:  All the error checking is nice, but there are
  still situations where a file or directory might be deleted, modified,
  etc. while you're iterating through the file tree.  Like in the
  `directory` method - the directory could have been deleted after the
  `isDirectory` check, but before `Files.walkFileTree` would have
  started to work ... so my pragmatic suggestion would actually be to
  just log the `IOException`s and add a bit of context (current file
  visited) with a wrapped exception or so.

Now that I went through all of this I'd say it looks okay, can be
cleaned up a bit like I wrote above.  Also maybe look at how other
command line programs behave, usually they don't even have a `-f` or
`-d` flag to switch between the two behaviours you have here and instead
accept an arbitrary number of file/directory arguments.